# Best way to define relation between server IP and virtual directory?

Tags: iis, virtual-directory, wireless

I have designed an IIS based library for a college on their server localhost and also I made a virtual directory which points to wwwroot to specify a proper name like "library". server is connected to a wireless modem. So when students want to use library they first connect to wireless Lan and then type http://library in their browsers.
this structure works fine for windows laptops but not for mobile phone users (Probably non-windows users). they have to type server IP (192.168.1.2) instead of http://library in their browser to gain access to library.

Where should I define a relation between server IP and the virtual directory  **library** so both laptops and cellphones can use http://library? on modem? on IIS manager? The student should setup something? or there is a mistake in virtual directory setup...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This likely means that "library" is not registered in DNS. In whatever you're using for your DNS server (Windows DNS, router, etc.), you'll want to create either a CNAME entry routing requests for "library" to the actual name of the server that IIS is hosted on or a regular A (HOST) entry (assuming the IIS server has a static IP) for "library" pointing to the server's IP address.

Comment: Thank you. Do o I need anymore creating a virtual directory by name of "library"? in other word in your way, is the "library" name of server or is yet the name of my virtual directory?

Comment: It is a 2nd name for the server so you probably don't need the virtual directory.

Comment: Thank you. last help plz that where should I define A entry or CNAME in a local computer? I had always used internet servers and made these setups through web based control panels.

Comment: On a single (Windows) machine, you can add an entry in the HOSTS file. Here is an article on how to edit the HOSTS file: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/. Add an entry that looks something like this: `192.168.1.50 library` where 192.168.1.50 is changed to the IP address of the server running the "library" application. Remember, this is just for adding it on 1 PC. To do it for all PCs, you'll need to add an A or CNAME record to your actual DNS server.